# Crystal Reports Redistributable Download (.NET 2003)

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

can any one help me where i can download Crystal Reports Redistributable Download (.NET 2003)

Answer (score 1):

Here is security updates provided by [microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17894).

[Download](http://tcsoftware.net/blog/2011/05/crystal-reports-redistributable-download-net-2005/) redistribution package

[Documentation](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Which+Crystal+Reports+assembly+versions+are+supported+in+which+versions+of+Visual+Studio+.NET?original_fqdn=wiki.sdn.sap.com) for Supported Version.

[Official Download](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?original_fqdn=wiki.sdn.sap.com&pageId=56787567)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response... download link you have mentioned is for VS 2005. But i would require for VS 2003. Do you have please

Comment: You made the change in your question, previously you mentioned about .NET 2005.

Comment: Hi Chandramohan, I updated my answer, kindly go through it.

Comment: Really Sorry Musakkhir, i realized the error after i posted then i changed the version from 2005 to 2003.Anyway thanks for the reply.